# Can I use SQL Server Compact Edition CE on Mono?

Tags: sql, mono, sql-server-ce

Does anyone know if I can use SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 on mono?

I'm hoping they are written as managed assemblies and will work ok..does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the SQL Compact (except System.Data.SqlCe.dll obviously) are native libraries, so no they won't work under non-Windows platforms.

Comment: interesting thought though eh? ;)

Comment: *"All of the SQL Compact (except System.Data.SqlCe.dll obviously) are native libraries"*: but System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is the *only* file required to use SQL Compact, and according to CorFlags it contains only managed code (ILONLY = 1). There are a few (10) P/Invoke declarations, so it probably wouldn't run on a non-Windows OS (except perhaps with Wine), but it would probably not require too much work to make it portable ;)

Comment: Negatory.  System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is only the managed proxy into the native DLLs.  You *must* have the native DLLs present, whether it's a desktop or a device.  Some devices ship with them in ROM so you don't have to distribute them with your app, but they still have to be there.

Answer (score 9):

Pretty replacement for SQL CE is SQLite

SQLite ADO.NET Provider is portable and exists on Microsoft.NET and Mono

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com

http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite

native components is exists for most major platforms and source code also available

Answer (score 1):

(By 'on mono' I assume you mean running on Mono in Linux?)

No. I'm pretty sure none of the SQL Server versions are built on managed assemblies.