# How to run MVC3 or newer application in Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mono

Default ASP .NET MVC 3 application is created using in Microsoft Web Developer Express 2010

Application is published to file system and copied to Debian server where mono 2.10.8 , Apache and mod_mono are installed.

Trying to run application causes error:

```
Server Error in '/mvc3test' Application

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace: 



System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type:type_is_assignable_from (System.Type,System.Type)
  at System.Type.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type c) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.RegisterBuildProvider (System.String extension, System.Type providerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (mono-2-10/70a5c95 Wed Feb 8 18:11:45 CET 2012); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

bin directory contains required dlls copied from windows:

```
EntityFramework.dll
mvc3test.dll
System.Web.Entity.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
mvc3test.pdb
EntityFramework.xml
```

so all required dlls are present

How to run mvc3 or mvc4 application in mono or fix this error ?

Comment: Have you considered using MonoDevelop to prevent errors like this? Maybe it would suffice to do the final compilation using it....

Comment: I have Visual Web Developer Express 2010 and Express for Web 2012 installed in my windows developing notebook and using them. I havent never tried Monodevelop. Should I really install MonoDevelop on windows or is there better way to solve this ?

Comment: Installing MonoDevelop and running the app locally on Mono is nothing big or time-consuming, still - you'd have the possiblity to check what it shows you about e.g. references or any other possible problems with configuration.

Comment: Mono isn't exactly .NET itself, so there may be some differences that you might get resolved by using their IDE. Can't promise you anything, but I guess it's worth a shot... As mŕowa already said, it's a matter of few minutes to get it up and running. Plus, you can always uninstall if it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more dll's required than those.  You should right click on your project and choose Add Deployable Dependencies, and then check the first two boxes (or all 3 if you're using sql ce)

See this http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Oh, and MVC4 is not currently supported by the 2.10.x branch.

Comment: Just remember SQL CE won't work outside Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2644464/3205

Answer (score 0):

check copy local = true especially for mvc.dll
`<private>true</private>` under the hint path in the csproj file