# Mono on Ubuntu Server and System.Web.Entiy

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I've a project developed with monodevelop and I've added to it and external reference for System.Web.Entity. This project run correctly on my local machine, so I've decided to port it on my server.
I create a new docker instance with ubuntu 15.10 (same on my local) and I install all mono dependencies.
I build my project and all works fine. Well, I put it on run with xsp4 and I suppose that all is ok but when I call a service request I get this error

`Can't find custom attr constructor image: /tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/23703349/assembly/shadow/b7cd78f2/34e8ce56_8325b6a4_00000001/System.Web.Entity.dll mtoken: 0x0a000022`

So I've try to "install" `System.Web.Entity` on local reference with

`gacutil -i System.Web.Entity.dll`

but in this case I receive  this error:

`Failure adding assembly System.Web.Entity.dll to the cache: Strong name cannot be verified for delay-signed assembly`

Now I can't understand what/where is the trouble because in local I had only insert a manual reference to System.Web.Entity.dll in monodevelop and then all is started without problem.

Anybody help me?

Comment: Which version of Mono do you have? on the status it's marked as fully implemented: http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Web.Entity

Comment: @LexLi In local i use correctly this service, I download dll file and add it to reference in monodevelop

Comment: @Gusman I'm using this version `Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.2 (Stable 4.2.2.30/996df3c Mon Feb 15 17:30:30 UTC 2016)`

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665751/how-to-run-mvc3-or-newer-application-in-mono