# Is there any support to sql server compact on android yet?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I was developing my application on windows mobile using sql server compact successfully, what I need now does this sql server compact is supported on android sdk ? One thing I want to use sql server compact on android instead of sql lite because of the database engine can read data in multiple thread / multiple connectivity at the same time when performing table lookup while the other connection is reading table. I cannot perform this action on sqllite, sqllite use file locking on its engine.

Does anyone facing this kind of problem like I did ?

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server Compact Edition comes with DLLs, so I'm pretty sure it won't work on Android devices (Linux)...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644464/can-i-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-on-mono

Comment: Err... you can access a SQLite database through multiple processes.  The only proviso is that only one of those threads can be writing.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining the tags `sql` and `server` does not mean that you are speaking of Microsfot SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In it's current form, sql server can't yet be supported by Android, which is why there is sql lite.