# Using an .mdf file instead of an MS SQL server on a linux environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono

I want to run an MVC application on a linux machine I have using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).  However, to my knowledge, I cannot run an MS SQL database on my linux machine.  However, would it not be possible to just save to an .MDF file instead to an actual SQL server, or is there more involved?  I apologize if the answer is incredibly obvious to some of you, but I just wanted to be sure before I start development on this application and end up heading in the wrong direction. I've tried looking online for answers, but there seems to be no answer that I can find.  Since it's just a file, not an actual running server, I would think that this implementation would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why not using `MySql` or `PostgreSql`?

Comment: @AlexJolig those are valid options as well, it's just that I need to do more research on how to implement those first. I'm asking this question just to get all the information I can about all my options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use SQL Server Compact Edition CE on Mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644464/can-i-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-on-mono)

Comment: "Just saving to a .mdf" is only possible if there's a specification of the format with documentation on what's actually done on saving. The correct approach is to use natively supported DB as commented by @AlexJolig