# Error in Porting c# winform application to RaspberryPi using Mono Compiler

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, mono, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a windows form application developed on visual studio 2012 and C# on my raspberry pi using mono compiler. But i get the following error.

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
   'System.Data.SqlServerCe
```

The database file is also included in the same folder from where my .exe runs. 
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can't do that. You're missing the Sql Server compact dll, and as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644464/can-i-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-on-mono), it's a native library and cannot be used with mono.

I think you will have to convert db/queries in something which is compatible with linux environment like SQLite [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi94aP6iaDXAhWM3KQKHUrEAGEQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fraspberrywebserver.com%2Fsql-databases%2Fset-up-an-sqlite-database-on-a-raspberry-pi.html&usg=AOvVaw1Q7al9OFYEMqLW8x_DlTej) or similar. Check also [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=112990) from the raspberry forums

Comment: I think your answer is true. Changing my database to  SQLite would be the only solution.

Comment: @Spark Well, that sucks. Good luck with that

Comment: Yes it would be difficult if i had a huge amount of data in db. but my database is really small with just 5 tables so it would be fine.